# Why is my JQuery push menu not working all of the sudden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jpanelmenu

My website is currently equipped with what used to be a fully functioning push menu, but now all of the sudden after playing around with the css, it doesn't want to work. I will provide my Code:

HTML

```
<div id="right">

  <div id="Top">

     <div id="menubar">

        <a id="menubarheader">DrumCenter</a>

        <a href="#menu" id="button" class="buttonicon"></a>

        <a href="#" id="searchlink" class="searchlink"></a>

     </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#right {

width: 100%;

background-color: #fff;

z-index: 5;

position: fixed;

left: 0px;

margin: 0px;

height: 100%;

-webkit-box-shadow:  -5px 0px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    moz-box-shadow:  -5px 0px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      o-box-shadow:  -5px 0px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        box-shadow:  -5px 0px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

}

#menu {

float:left;

width: 80%;

height: 100%;

}

#menu li {

background-color: white;

border-bottom: 1px solid #c8c8c8;

}

#Top {

width: inherit;

height: 80px;

margin: 0px;

}

#menubar, #menubarheader {

    width: inherit;

    height: 80px;

}

#menubar {

    min-width: 250px;

    position: absolute;

    background: #fff;

    border-bottom: 3px solid #ABABA0;

line-height: 80px;

}

#button, #menubarheader, #searchlink {

    position: absolute;

    vertical-align: middle;

    font-weight: lighter;

}

#button {

    text-decoration: none;

    padding-left: 5%;

}

.buttonicon {

font-family: "glyphs";

    text-decoration: none;

    font-size:  230%;

    color: gray;

}

.buttonicon:before {

content: "\e696";

}

#searchlink{

    text-decoration: none;

    padding-left: 87%

}

.searchlink{

font-family: "icomoon";

    text-decoration: none;

    font-size:  150%;

    color: gray;

}

.searchlink:before {

content: "\e67f";

}

#menubarheader {

    text-align: center;

    color: #0099FF;

    font-size: 200%;

    vertical-align: middle;

}
```

Javascript

```
$('#button').toggle( 
        function() {
            $('#right').animate({ left: 250 }, 'fast', function() {
                $('#button');
            });
        }, 
        function() {
            $('#right').animate({ left: 0 }, 'fast', function() {
                $('#button');
            });
        }
    );
```

Before you ask, yes I have linked the proper jquery in my HTML, I just didn't provide it on here. What I would like to know is why this has ceased to work, and how I can fix this? I am very confused about this. Thank you! If you would like to see my website that I am talking about, you can go to (http://www.codesrce.com/thedrumcenter) But you will only see what I am talking about if your screen width is 1399px or less because that is the mobile site.

Comment: for starters you have to set the `z-index` of your `#button` to a big number so it is appeared upfront of the `#menubarheader`, and secondly I can't find the js code you wrote here in your website? where did you write it?

Comment: Yeah the z-index was set that way just so nothing will ever overlap that element. I tried changing that, but it didn't fix anything. I have the code in the head of my HTML. I don't understand why this menu just stopped working. It was working fine yesterday with everything like it is here, but now it doesn't work. @AminJafari

Comment: Also this is only my mobile site, so if your screen is larger than 1399px, you will get the desktop site. @AminJafari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're writing the script before jQuery is loaded, cut it and then paste it after all the `<script></script>` tags are called, and it will be fixed!

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried this but it didn't do anything. I had the script where it was yesterday, and it worked fine. I am so confused why it stopped working.

Comment: I just figured out that when I delete out #searchlink item completely, the problem is fixed. Any ideas on why the #searchlink hyperlink would interfere with my #button? @aminjafari

Comment: but you copied it after the html tag, that means it is not read! try copying it RIGHT AFTER the script tags are called, in the head tag!

Comment: Okay I get what you are saying now. But it's weird, it only works when I delete the search button from the #menubarheader, which I would like to keeo if possible. Any solutions on how to keep a search hyperlink, while not interfering with the menu button?

Comment: because you're giving it `padding-left:87%;`. remove it and position the `#searchlink` by CSS left and top which you can do easily because it is positioned absolute!

Comment: simply instead of `padding-left:87%` write `left:87%`